# Reading from vectors C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, entities

What is wrong with this code? It detects whether I've reached the coordinates of a monster but only one of them, or the closest one at least. If I travel to other coordinates it doesn't tell me the monster has appeared. Don't know why because I am looping through the monster vector every time I type 'north'.
Here is the code.

Monster Class:

```
class Monster
{
    public:
        std::vector<std::string> names;
        std::vector<double> posx; // North - South
        std::vector<double> posy; // East - West

        bool compareCoords(double monsterPosX, double monsterPosY);
        void cMonster(std::string monsterName, double monsterPosX, double monsterPosY);
        void randomSpawn();

    protected:

    private:
};
```

compareCoords to detect whether a monster already exists at those coordinates and the cMonster (create monster) functions:

```
void Monster::cMonster(std::string monsterName, double monsterPosX, double monsterPosY)
{
    if (compareCoords(monsterPosX, monsterPosY) == false)
    {
        names.push_back(monsterName);
        posx.push_back(monsterPosX);
        posy.push_back(monsterPosY);
        std::cout << "Monster " << monsterName << " has been created at X: " << monsterPosX << " Y: " << monsterPosY << std::endl;
    }
}

bool Monster::compareCoords(double monsterPosX, double monsterPosY)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < posx.size(); i++)
    {
        if (monsterPosX == posx[i] && monsterPosY == posy[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Monster newenemy;
    Character newplayer;

    newenemy.cMonster("Weezo", 1, 0);
    newenemy.cMonster("Weezo", 2, 0);

    newplayer.posx.push_back(0);
    newplayer.posy.push_back(0);

    home:

    std::cout << "-->> ";
    std::string userInput;
    std::cin.clear();

    getline(std::cin, userInput);

    if (!userInput.compare("north"))
    {
        newplayer.headNorth();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newenemy.names.size(); i++)
        {
            if (newplayer.posx[i] == newenemy.posx[i] && newplayer.posy[i] == newenemy.posy[i])
            {
                std::cout << "A " << newenemy.names[i] << " has appeared." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (!userInput.compare("south"))
    {
        newplayer.headSouth();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newenemy.posx.size(); i++)
        {
            if (newplayer.posx[i] == newenemy.posx[i] && newplayer.posy[i] == newenemy.posy[i])
            {
                std::cout << "A " << newenemy.names[i] << " has appeared." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "You have entered an invalid command." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[image]

^ As you can see here, it shows when I'm at the coordinates of Gorilla but not the second monster, Donald Trump. It just ignores the second one.

I've been stuck here for hours, I don't understand what could be wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You're comparing coordinates of `posx` and `posy` inside of cMonster beacuse you actually insert anything into those vectors. so that'll always return false.

Comment: Also, it looks like your `Monster` class is actually a factor for monsters. Usually it's 1 Monster object per actual Monster.

Comment: Comparing `double`s for strict equality after computations is rarely a good idea, because of floating-point errors. Try using integers if you can, or compare using a small threshold to decide whether two numbers are close enough to be considered equal.

Comment: Why does the character class have multiple coordinates? Is the `Character` class also a collection of multiple characters? Most likely the mistake here is that you are comparing the position of the nth character against the nth monster. Try something like `newplayer.posx[0] == newenemy.posx[i]` etc. instead and see if it works as you intend.

Comment: How can I make more than one object without having to do this: Monster newmonster; Monster newmonster2; Monster newmonster3 etc..? Gill, it compares when I use the randomSpawn function which I didn't show. All works fine there, I just need more than one entity to exist at the same time. I have a command to check the entities and it does show the vectors are working for them so I'm confused.